# What is the name of our Solar System?

Tags: solar-system, naming

what is our Solar System called rather than "the Solar System"?

I've found "Sol System" and "Monmatia", too, but is there more to it?

Comment: Where have you found these names?

Comment: "Monmatia" seems to be an invention of the [Urantians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Urantia_Book).

Comment: That's right. I found Monmatia in Urantians.

Comment: Sol system is danish for solar system.

Answer (score 12):

It's just called "the Solar System". (Plenty of places and objects have names like that; it's no different from "the Arctic" or "the Moon" or "the Sun".)

("Sol system" is an invention of science fiction writers; it has no general use outside some science fiction contexts. Anything else is going to be something similar, or general crackpottery of one kind or another.)

Comment: It should probably be noted that 'Solar' is a adjective form of Sol, just as Polar is to Pole. And that Sol is just the latin name for the Sun.

Comment: The first known usage of the word *Sol* for the sun is in the Ashmole Manuscript Treatise on Astrology circa 1450.

Comment: @arkon I guess you mean first *in English*?

Answer (score 7):

The solar system was named long before we knew that other solar systems existed. Just like the Sun is not the only Sun in the universe but we still call it the Sun.

Comment: nice answer . simple

Comment: It's interesting, because there is actually a lot of disagreement about the general use of the word "Sun". In Astronomy, usually Sun means only *our* star. Others claim that Sun can, and should, be used to reference any star nearest the planet, citing historical use in fiction. A lot of people also use 'Sun' interchangeably with 'star'. The actual meaning becomes somewhat ambiguous due to this.

Comment: @MitchGoshorn I agree and the same applies to The Moon =). We just discovered The Sun is just another ordinary star instead of the greatest God-like object in the sky. Take times to get used to it

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question succinctly, the Solar System also goes by the names: The Copernican System, The Heliocentric System, and The Planetary System, in addition to the ones you have mentioned. There aren't too many other names, actually, so just stick to Solar System since it's the most widely accepted.

Comment: Would you say to a Klingon, “I come from the Heliocentric System” ?